# Java printing an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, printing, tostring

I know there are a lot of pages about this question, but I cannot understand it in my case.

I need to print the array of objects. For example, I have an array of objects that hold objects from the "shape" class. Do I call the toString method for each object in the array, or do I code the toString method in ObjectList to print out the instance variables? If so, how do I do that?

```
public class Shape{
    private String shapeName;
    private int numSides;

    public String toString(){
        return shapeName + " has " + numSides + " sides.";
    }
}

public class ObjectList{
    private Object[] list = new Object[10];
    private int numElement = 0;

    public void add(Object next){
        list[numElement] = next;
    }

    public String toString(){
        // prints out the array of objects 

        // do I call the toString() method from the object?

        // or do I print the instance variables? What am I printing?

        // I'm guessing I do a for loop here
    }
}

public class Driver{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ObjectList list = new ObjectList();
        Shape square = new Shape("square", 4);
        Shape hex = new Shape("hexagon", 6);
        list.add(square);
        list.toString();  // prints out array of objects
}
```

I am aiming for it to print this:

```
square has 4 sides
hexagon has 6 sides
```

Comment: If the array only holds `Shape`s, why not make it a `Shape[]` rather than `Object[]`? Also your `add` method should increase the value of `numElement`.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to add the `numElement++`, but I wanted to make it dynamic for all objects, and not just the Shape[] class.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is use Arrays.toString:

```
Arrays.toString(myArray);
```

This will internally call the `toString` method of every element of your array.

So just override `toString` method in your `Shape` class and it should work fine.

To add further, override `toString` method in your class where you call `Arrays.toString` on your variable `list` :

```
public class ObjectList{
    private Object[] list = new Object[10];
    .............

    public String toString(){
         return Arrays.toString(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP does not want to print all `10` objects, only the ones that have been added.

Comment: @pbabcdefp I guess that should be automatically handled by Arrays class

Comment: Downvoter, please comment, what was wrong with my answer

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the answer.

Comment: I'm afraid it was me, sorry. The OP specified that only the 2 shapes added should be printed, whereas your answer prints the 2 shapes plus `null` 8 times.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with bellowed code, make for loop in toString method to print each shape object.

```
class Shape{
    private String shapeName;
    private int numSides;

    Shape(String shapeName, int numSides){
        this.shapeName = shapeName;
        this.numSides = numSides;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return shapeName + " has " + numSides + " sides.";
    }
}

class ObjectList{
    private Object[] list = new Object[10];
    private int numElement = 0;

    public void add(Object next){
        list[numElement] = next;
        numElement++;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String str="";
        int i=0;
        while(list[i] != null){
            str += list[i]+"\n";
            i++;
        }
        return str;
    }
}

public class Driver{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ObjectList list = new ObjectList();
        Shape square = new Shape("square", 4);
        Shape hex = new Shape("hexagon", 6);
        list.add(hex);
        list.add(square);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a for-each statement in toString() of Object List and create a large String with '\n' characters and return it as a String  . Or may be name displayListElement() will be semantically more correct in which you can simple print all the Objects in the list  .

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you should call `toString` method for each of objects that you want to print and join them together. You can use `StringBuilder` to hold the string-in-the-making as follows:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i <= numElements; i++) {
        result.append(list.toString() + "\n");
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Note that you need to increase `numElements` (e.g. `numElements++`) for each `add` operation as what pbabcdefp said in the comments. Also, you can use `ArrayList` class to manage "growing arrays".